# How to change border style with multiple input using loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

How to change border style with multiple input using `for` loop with JavaScript?

When I fill `1` into every input `type="text"` and then press submit button.

It's changes border style only

```
<input type="text" id="price1" size="20" name="price[]">
```

But I want to change border style all 3 input with `for` loop.

How to do that ?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<div id="p_scents_price">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts_price">
            <input type="text" id="price1" size="20" name="price[]">
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="p_scents_price">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts_price">
            <input type="text" id="price2" size="20" name="price[]">
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="p_scents_price">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts_price">
            <input type="text" id="price3" size="20" name="price[]">
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function checkform ( form )
{
  var z = 1;
  for(var z=1;z<10;z++) 
  {
    if ((document.getElementById("price"+z).value != "") && (document.getElementById("price"+z).value < "1.5")) {
      document.getElementById("price"+z).style.border = "1px solid red";
      return false ;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("price"+z).style.border = "1px solid #d5d5c5";
    }
  }
return true ;
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues there:

1. You cannot use the same `id` on more than one element
2. The `for` attribute on a `label` must refer to the **form field** that it relates to, not a `div`
3. You don't need or want a `for` attribute on a `label` that contains the `input` it relates to
4. This: `document.getElementById("price"+z).value < "1.5"` does a **string** comparison. If you want to compare numbers, remove the quotes from `1.5` and JavaScript's algorithm for `<` will convert the `value` string to a number before doing the comparison. Or, since the number is entered by a person, you may want to use `parseInt(..., 10)` to explicitly ensure that you parse it in base 10, although `parseInt` allows extra characters after the number.
5. In your code, the first time an element's value is `< "1.5"`, you do `return false`. That stops the loop. You might want to have a variable, `isValid` or similar, that you set `true` to start with and then set `false` when you find a problem, then return that.
6. Your loop goes from `1` to `10` but you only have three `priceN` inputs. Rather than hardcoding loop limits, it's usually best to let the markup drive the code.
7. The `=1` in `var z=1` is pointless if you do it again on the next line; similarly, declaring a variable twice is pointless
8. When you find yourself repeatedly calling a function to get the same thing over and over and over again (`document.getElementById("price"+z")`), consider doing it only once and saving the result to a variable

A few suggestions (see comments):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<div><!-- Change: Removed `id` from these divs -->
    <p>
        <label><!-- Change: Removed `for` from these labels -->
            <!-- Change: Changed `id="priceN"` to `class="price"` on these inputs -->
            <input type="text" class="price" size="20" name="price[]">
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" class="price" size="20" name="price[]">
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" class="price" size="20" name="price[]">
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
// Change: Rewrote; also removed archaic <!-- comments, you don't need them
function checkform ( form )
{
  // Get a list of all of the elements with the "price" class
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(".price");
  var z;
  var input;
  var isValid = true;
  var value;

  // Loop through the list
  for (z = 0; z < list.length; ++z) {
    console.log("z = " + z);
    // Get this input
    input = list[z];

    // Check its value
    if (input.value != "" && parseInt(input.value, 10) < 1.5) {
      // Not valid, set border and flag that the form is invalid
      input.style.border = "1px solid red";
      isValid = false;
    }
    else {
      // Valid, clear any previous red border
      input.style.border = "1px solid #d5d5c5";
    }
  }

  // Return result
  return isValid;
}
</script>
```

Working example:

```js
// Change: Rewrote; also removed archaic <!-- comments, you don't need them
function checkform ( form )
{
  // Get a list of all of the elements with the "price" class
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(".price");
  var z;
  var input;
  var isValid = true;
  var value;

  // Loop through the list
  for (z = 0; z < list.length; ++z) {
    console.log("z = " + z);
    // Get this input
    input = list[z];

    // Check its value
    if (input.value != "" && parseInt(input.value, 10) < 1.5) {
      // Not valid, set border and flag that the form is invalid
      input.style.border = "1px solid red";
      isValid = false;
    }
    else {
      // Valid, clear any previous red border
      input.style.border = "1px solid #d5d5c5";
    }
  }

  // Return result
  return isValid;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
  <div><!-- Change: Removed `id` from these divs -->
    <p>
      <label><!-- Change: Removed `for` from these labels -->
        <!-- Change: Changed `id="priceN"` to `class="price"` on these inputs -->
        <input type="text" class="price" size="20" name="price[]">
      </label>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="text" class="price" size="20" name="price[]">
      </label>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="text" class="price" size="20" name="price[]">
      </label>
    </p>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: @robertwisyert: I missed that you had a couple of extra curly braces. Fixed. But if you're using jQuery (I see you're including it, but not using it), you probably wan to look at various jQuery examples for form validation.

Comment: your code are best , but i want to use on ie7 too , and ie7 not support `querySelectorAll`. Could you please give me some code that work on ie7 ?

Comment: @robertwisyert: Read the jQuery documentation. It handles dealing with issues like `querySelectorAll` not being on IE7 and earlier for you.

Comment: can i use `document.getElementsByClassName` ?

Comment: @robertwisyert: Read the jQuery documentation. You're including a powerful tool on your page. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your `for` loop probably only needs to go to three.

`for(var z = 1; z < 3; z++)`

Also, you don't need to define the variable `z` twice.

```
var z = 1; // This can go.
for(var z = 1; z < 3; z++)
```

Some other minor re-factorings produces this which should do the trick.

```
function checkform (form)
{
    var isValidForm = true;
    for(var z = 1; z <= 3; z++) 
    {
        var inputValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price" + z).value);

        if (!isNaN(inputValue) && inputValue < 1.5) {
            document.getElementById("price" + z).style.border = "1px solid red";
            isValidForm = false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("price" + z).style.border = "1px solid #d5d5c5";
        }
    }

    return isValidForm;
}
```

Alternatively you could use JQuery:

```
function checkForm(){

    var isFormValid = true;

    // Get all text inputs that have an ID starting with 'price' and loop through them
    $('input[type=text][id^=price]').each(function(){

         // Get the current loop item.
         var currentItem = $(this);

         // Convert it's value to a number.
         var inputValue = parseFloat(currentItem.val());

         // If it's invalid make it red.
         if (!isNaN(inputValue) && inputValue < 1.5) {
            currentItem.css('border', '1px solid red');
            isValidForm = false;
         }else{
             // Otherwise, make it this colour.
             currentItem.css('border', '1px solid #d5d5c5');
         } 
    });
}
```